# Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition... in react with store and clickhandler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

EDIT:
It seems that this warning has something to do with my input range component. I will search for the problem and ask here, if I can`t find the problem. Thanx

I searched here and some other threads, but could`t find a solution.
I am creating a questionnaire with some dynamic pages, where I can answer radio buttons, checkboxes etc.

When I click the next button, current values will be stored and the new Page comes.

I realized it with a counter for the pages.
If the counter reaches the and of the Pages a result Page will be shown.

When I click the next buttons all seems to work, but I get the warning:

Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

I reduced the code for showing here. I hope this is ok.

this is the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: moment(),
      values: {}
    };
}
```

render function:

```
render() {
    const {show_result} = this.props;


    if(!show_result) {
        return (
            <div className="applicationbody">
                {this.renderActiveForm()}
            </div>
            );
    } else {
        const {children} = this.props; 
        return (
            <div className="applicationbody">
                {children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

renderActivForm function:

```
renderActiveForm = () => {
    const {page_now, count_cats, count_pages, categories_pages_quantity, language, catValuesCountAll, cat_values} = this.props;

    return (
        <div className="applicationbody__form">
            {page_now.block.map((oneblock, i) => {
                return (
                    this.renderReturnInput(oneblock, i)
                );
            })}
          <div className="ButtonBar">
            <a className="button"
               onClick={this.save}>weiter</a>
          </div>
       </div>
    );
}
```

save function:

```
save = () => {
    const {page_now, count_cats, count_pages, categories_pages_quantity, catValuesCountAll} = this.props;
    const cat_new = (count_pages + 1) === categories_pages_quantity.cats[count_cats].pages ? (count_cats + 1) : count_cats;
    const page_new = (count_pages + 1) === categories_pages_quantity.cats[count_cats].pages ? 0 : (count_pages + 1);

    if (page_now.evaluate === "1") {
        var cat_value_of_this_page = sum(this.state.values);

        function sum( obj ) {
            var sum = 0;
            for( var el in obj ) {
            if( obj.hasOwnProperty( el ) ) {
                sum += parseFloat( obj[el] );
            }
            }
            return sum;
        }
        catValuesCountAll(page_new);
    } else {

    }
}
```

the catValuesCountAll action only increments the pagenow, so the new page with ne questions is shown. But why I get the warning?

I would be very happy if somebody could help me here.

EDIT:
It seems that this warning has something to do with my input range component. I will search for the problem and ask here, if I can`t find the problem. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem now. The [input-range component](https://github.com/davidchin/react-input-range) want to have a state for the min and max values.
So I setted the state during the rendering, cause it had to be dynamic. But now I set the state in componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps and the warning is gone.